# Change shell prompt based on container name?

Tags: linux, shell, lxc, kde

I have been doing a lot of work using Linux containers, and I keep forgetting which of the terminals on my screen is running inside which container, particularly when I leave them open overnight.

How can I change the shell prompt, or the terminal title based on the container that the shell runs in?

This is a general question, but it'd be great if it worked for `systemd-nspawn` and `kde` on Arch.

Comment: Can you see any kind of container ID/name in the `env` and `set` output?

Comment: @Kondybas: no. I don't think there is supposed to be any, `systemd-nspawn` even cleans up the environment before instantiating the container.

Comment: And how do you tell one from another?

Comment: @Kondybas: from inside the container, you can't, just like you can't tell which host you ssh'd into if they were installed from the same configuration before you started customizing (hostname, ...)

Comment: So the most straightforward way is to set environment variable just after instantiation and then to use it as ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your containers use distinct UTS namespaces then set a unique hostname in each one. For instance, things like docker set the hostname value to the container hash ID as a default in the UTS namespace associated with the main container process.

Thus with a `PS1` pattern using the hostname variable you will know in which container you are when running a bash prompt.